# Performing same operation on multiple functions

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, option-type

I have a class with multiple `get` functions such as `getF1` to `getF10`. I want, for each of these getters, to replace the letter `"x"` to an `"a"` (random example). The getter can return a null value.

So far, this is what I have done and it works, is there a way to get something better looking than this?

```
public void foo(final MyObject bar) {
    Optional.of(bar).map(MyObject::getF1).ifPresent(s -> bar.setF1(s.replaceAll("x", "a"));
    Optional.of(bar).map(MyObject::getF2).ifPresent(s -> bar.setF2(s.replaceAll("x", "a")));
    ...
    Optional.of(bar).map(MyObject::getF10).ifPresent(s -> bar.setF10(s.replaceAll("x", "a")));
}
```

I was thinking of something like this, using a list, obviously, this code is wrong but you get the idea:

```
public void foo(final MyObject bar) {
    List<Function> func = new ArrayList<Function>();
    func.addAll(Arrays.asList(MyObject::getF1, MyObject::getF2, ..., MyObject::getF10));
    Optional.of(bar).map(func).ifPresent(s -> func(s.replaceAll("x", "a"));
}
```

Maybe working with a stream could get the job done?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the fields `F1` ... `F10` generated or do you create them manually?

Comment: The third line `Optional.of(bar).map(MyObject::getF10).ifPresent(s -> bar.setF3(s.replaceAll("x", "a")));` - is getting `F10` and setting `F3` intentional or a typo?

Comment: If F1 - F10 are of the same type, could you store them as an array inside your object and create a generic `get()` method where you specify the index 1-10. That way you could loop through and do the same operation to each in a for loop.

Comment: @Nikolas It was a typo indeed

Comment: @Nikolas F1 to F10 are String generated by the inputs of the user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the mappers used in `Optional::map` and consumers used in `Optional::ifPresent` in a `Map`.

I also recommend you to create a method to avoid the code duplication for the String replacement which shall be called easily. This is useful since all the replacements are the same

```
private String replaced(String string) {
    return string.replaceAll("x", "a");
}
```

Then simply iterate over the entries and apply each of the key-value pairs (the order doesn't matter):

```
Map<Function<? super MyObject, ? extends String>, Consumer<? super String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(MyObject::getF1, bar::setF1);
map.put(MyObject::getF2, bar::setF2);
map.put(MyObject::getF10, bar::setF10);
// ...

map.forEach((function, consumer) -> {
        Optional.of(bar).map(function).map(this::replaced).ifPresent(consumer);
});
```

---

If you want to extend this mechanism and apply a different function to each String passed to the setter, then you need also to use a different structure:

```
public final class Mapping {

    private final Function<MyObject, String> getterFunction;
    private final Function<String, String> transformationFunction;
    private final Consumer<String> setterFunction;

    public Mapping(final Function<MyObject, String> getterFunction, final Function<String, String> transformationFunction,
        final Consumer<String> setterFunction) {
        this.getterFunction = getterFunction;
        this.transformationFunction = transformationFunction;
        this.setterFunction = setterFunction;
    }

    // getters
}
```

And the usage is similar (the transformation functions are samples and might vary):

```
List<Mapping> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Mapping(MyObject::getF1, s -> s.replaceAll("x", "a"), bar::setF1));
list.add(new Mapping(MyObject::getF2, s -> s.replaceAll("x", "a"), bar::setF2));
list.add(new Mapping(MyObject::getF10, s -> s.replaceAll("x", "a"), bar::setF10));

list.forEach(mapping -> {
    Optional.of(bar)
            .map(mapping.getGtterFunction)
            .map(mapping.getTransformationFunction)
            .ifPresent(mapping.getSetterFunction);
});
```

Comment: Getting a NPE on `Optional.map(Optional.java:215)`, line is `return Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(value));`. Not sure why though, Optional should take care of null? Moreover, I don't have any null in my test.

Comment: Optional takes care after the null results. The NPE is throw if the mapper itself is null. I am unable to debug it from here. Debug your code and detect what fails and eventually provide me a link to your code (don’t copy the full code here) and I take a look.

Comment: Alright, I think I can take care of the rest, thanks a lot for your help and explanations.

Comment: I had NPE because I wrote `replaced` in an other class and called it with @Inject. I have to manually instanciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate your getters and setters as paired [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)s and [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html)s:

```
public void foo(final MyObject bar) {

    if (bar == null)
        return;

    Map<Supplier<String>, Consumer<String>> funcs = new HashMap<>();
    funcs.put(bar::getF1, bar::setF1);
    funcs.put(bar::getF2, bar::setF2);

    funcs.forEach(
            (getter, setter) -> Optional.of(getter.get()).ifPresent(s -> setter.accept(s.replaceAll("x", "a"))));
}
```

Also note that the `null` argument handling by `Optional` has been replaced by a guard clause: This has to come before resolving the `bar::...` to prevent an NPE. It also makes the intended `null` handling clearer.

Comment: This doesn't differ from my answer, moreover the `s.replaceAll("x", "a")` is fixed and the individual transformation for each field couldn't be applied.

Comment: @Nikolas, I disagree: While there is the similarity of using a `Map` to pair the functions, my answer 1) uses `Supplier`s on the `bar` object and 2) makes note of the NPE danger. So, there are indeed differences. (BTW, the individually different transformations per field are not in the original question.)

Comment: Silently returning nothing violates the fail-fast principle, which is wrong and leads to hidden bugs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. While failing fast would certainly be desirable in case of an error condition, this does not seem to apply here: The explicit `Optional.of(bar)` in the original question indicates that 1) `null` is a valid argument, and 2) nothing should be done in that case. The guard clause merely makes these semantics explicit. I have edited the answer to make this clearer.